# RegEx for matching structured addresses

Tags: regex

I have a regex that I need to add on to

[regex](https://rubular.com/r/1UytX9KYPY4kjs)

```
^\d*(?: ?\d+ ?[&\/-] ?\d+)? +([\w.]+(?: +\w+)*) *
```

I am essentially trying to parse out the door number from addresses but I have come across data that do not have the door number but just the street name. In this case I want to return the street name but my current regex does not match it correctly. I need to make the last line pass in the above link.

```
2 Main Street -> 'Main Street'

5 & 6 Shore Lane -> 'Shore Lane'

7/8 Bay Way -> 'Bay Way'

73-97 Park Dr E -> 'Park Dr E'

2781  Boyle Street -> 'Boyle Street'

267 1/2 Brad St -> 'Brad St'

433 W. 49th St. -> 'W 49th St'

One  Building Road -> 'One Building Road'
```

Comment: Please post all the details here, not just at a remote site.

Comment: @Thefourthbird That gets rid of the first word 'One' which I want to match on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No use making `[ ]+` required if everything before it is optional.

`^\d*(?:[ ]?\d+[ ]?[&\/-][ ]?\d+)?[ ]*([\w.]+(?:[ ]+\w+)*)`

https://regex101.com/r/EiNNaz/1

---

However, if you require separation between an optional *House Number*
and the *Street Name*, you have to get a little creative.

Restrict the first letter of the *Street Name* to a non-digit word `[^\W\d]`
and use a whitespace *Boundary* `(?<!\S)` before it.
Thus, all is well

`^\d*(?:[ ]?\d+[ ]?[&\/-][ ]?\d+)?[ ]*((?<!\S)[^\W\d][\w.]*(?:[ ]+\w+)*)`

https://regex101.com/r/PsJled/1

This one's readable regex is

```
 ^ 
 \d* 
 (?: [ ]? \d+ [ ]? [&\/-] [ ]? \d+ )?
 [ ]* 
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?<! \S )
      [^\W\d] 
      [\w.]* 
      (?: [ ]+ \w+ )*
 )                             # (1 end)
```

---

There is also this looser one you can try
https://regex101.com/r/xasb3S/1

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the spacing between the street number and street name into the optional first group.

```
^\d*(?: ?\d+ ?[&\/-] ?\d+ +)?([\w.]+(?: +\w+)*) *
```

That is move the `+` part into the group. Change:

```
...\d+)? +(...
```

To:

```
...\d+ +)? (...
```

Comment: That breaks my cases 1,5,7

Answer (score 0):

What about `(^[\s&/\-1-9]+){0,1}(.*)` and then target subgroup 2